# Change both the code name and the shape name of an activex optionbutton control in Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, activex, excel-2007

**Excel VBA:**
I am trying to get to some activex option buttons through the OLEObjects object, but I am finding that even though I change the value of (Name) in the property window for the object, it still requires the "OptionButton1" default name as a key.

I know that some of the objects in Excel VBA have a code name and another name which is also the one used for the key to get to it from OLEObjects, but I don't know how I can change this "other" name.

I am passing in my object name as a parameter (basically) to a function, so I can't just do :

```
ActiveSheet.optMyNewName.Value
```

or whatever.  I need to be able to do this:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("optMyNewName").Object.Value
```

but currently only this works:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("OptionButton1").Object.Value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a string into the OLEObjects collection, it uses the Caption property as the key.  Pass the caption as the parameter and it should work.